# convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n !}{n !+3} $?

Tags: convergence-divergence

determine the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n !}{n !+3}
$$

I tried using the ratio test and also for n! , I use Stirling approximation.Still I got stuck.

Comment: A *necessary* condition for $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ to converge is $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=0$, which is clearly not fulfilled in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n!+3}=1\ne0$, your series diverges.

Comment: Sorry your answer is not cleared to me

Comment: I am just using the fact that, if a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. In your case, that limit is $1$, not $0$. Is it clear now?

Comment: yes! thanks .It is now clear to me

Comment: So,  when to use ratio test / root test etc... actually I am getting confused to deal with the inspection to study the nature of series!

Comment: I am sorry, but there is no test to decide which test you should use. However, if $a_n$ is something raised to the power $n$, I suggest that you use the root test. And if $a_n$ is a product, I suggest that you use the ratio test. But the most basic of all tests os to determine whether or not $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: clear! thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 2):

A series $\sum a_n$ cannot converge unless $a_n \to 0$. Here $a_n \to 1$ so it is not convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Upper bound (take $n!+3 \geq n!$): $a_n \leq 1$, so $\sum_{n}a_n \to_n \infty$

Lower bound (take $n! + 3 \leq 2 n!): a_n \geq \frac{1}{2}$, so $\sum_n a_n \to_n \infty$

So the sum diverges. In fact only the lower bound would do.